# if exist then insert else update for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using `SQL server 2012`.

I have two tables. I want to `UPDATE` second table.

I am trying to use `if exists then insert else update` concept. but it is for single record. I want to check whole table.So it not possible to give primary key value every time.

simply, I have to scan the first table and parellaly update second table.
so please give me the script for it.

Comment: Can you show us the table schema as well as your queries?

Comment: i have taken simple example. table contains one column as sizeCd with size char(7)

Comment: You could run an `UPDATE` command first then do something like `IF @ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT ...`. The `INSERT` statement will only happen if no row was updated by the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @ving are Both The Table Have Same Schema And Column Name

Comment: @vinG It will good IF You Show the Table Structure of BOTH Table

Comment: should i use cursor ?

Comment: @vinG provide Table structre

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed yes both have same structure with one column SizeCode char(7)

Comment: may be it should be Insert if not exist else update record.

Comment: but it works for single record.I want to scan whole table contains more than 10000 records.so how to use that concept for more recors

Comment: If you have one-to-one relationship between two tables - use MERGE. Else you must use WHILE-loop or CURSOR.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

First Run Dynamic Generated Query for UPDATE

```
SELECT 'UPDATE TABLEA SET SizeCode ='''+SizeCode+''' ', FROM TABLEB WHERE SizeCode IN (SELECT SizeCode FROM TableA)
```

Once All The Existing Data Got Updated You Have simply Run Insert statement which are Not Present In Table A.

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE SizeCode NOT IN (SELECT SizeCode FROM TableA)
```

OR

```
  INSERT INTO TableA (SizeCode )
    SELECT SizeCode  FROM TABLEB WHERE SizeCode NOT IN (SELECT SizeCode FROM TableA)
```

Comment: please correct second query
`INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE SizeCode NOT IN (SELECT SizeCode FROM TableB)`

Comment: What's Wrong It.It will work for you Even Though I Had modify The Ans Check It.

Comment: IF you just run SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE SizeCode NOT IN (SELECT SizeCode FROM TableA) This will give you list of Data which are not Present IN Table. IF Any Issue Let me Know

Answer (score 0):

try this this will check data is not present then it insert record else will update data

Change statement as per your table due to I have not any idea about your tables

```
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EmailsRecebidos 
                   WHERE De = @_DE
                   AND Assunto = @_ASSUNTO
                   AND Data = @_DATA)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO EmailsRecebidos (De, Assunto, Data)
       VALUES (@_DE, @_ASSUNTO, @_DATA)
   END
   ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE EmailsRecebidos  SET A = 'a'  WHERE De = @_DE
                   AND Assunto = @_ASSUNTO
                   AND Data = @_DATA
END

END
```